# Can you skip a record on bulk import when a duplicate record shows up?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm diving into some code written by others and I'm running into a duplicate record issue. I understand why the duplicate issue is popping up (I added the unique_together constraint). This code below is wrapped with the @transaction.atomic decorator so if any part fails it rolls back. I want to have the serializer is_valid() function skip over the duplicates, just move on, and not raise the ValidationError. How can I do this and is this the best practice?

The code makes use of the Django Rest Framework serializers and validators.

```
serializer_class = globals().get(table + 'Serializer')
if serializer_class is None:
    raise SerializerNotFound(table)
serializer = serializer_class(data=data, many=True)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
serializer.save()
```

I also added this code to the Serializer class:

```
class Meta:
    model = CoolModelName
    validators = [
        validators.UniqueTogetherValidator(
            queryset=CoolModelName.objects.all(),
            fields=('field', 'list', 'names', 'here')
        )
    ]
```